# Double tap and click conflict (jQuery and Hammer.js )

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I'm trying something crazy, I'd like to implement an Instagram feature: twice taps to like.

So, I'm using the latest versions of jQuery and Hammer.js. I'm not an advanced professional, but I've tried to write a JavaScript code to identify which event is.

```js
var postDoubleTapped;
postDoubleTapped = false;

Hammer($('.post').get(0)).on('doubletap', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  postDoubleTapped = true;

  console.log('Double tap!');
  return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.post a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(postDoubleTapped);

  setTimeout((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      if (!postDoubleTapped) {
        location.href = $(_this).attr('href');
      }
      postDoubleTapped = false;
    };
  })(this), 500);
  return false;
});
```

As you can see on example (http://codepen.io/caio/pen/vqEjc) it didn't work. The console returns:

[image: Console]

**There is another problem, I can't reproduce the `_blank` target on `a` tag.**

Is it the better method to do it? Am I on the right way? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way but the double tap is like clicking two times. So you use hammer in both cases like this:

```
var i=0;
Hammer($('.post').get(0)).on('doubletap', function(event) {
    i++;
    console.log( 'double tap' + i );
});

$(".post a").hammer();
$(".post a").on('tap', function (event) {
    i++;
    console.log( 'single tap' + i );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the redirect yourself, you can trigger the click programmatically:

```
fireEvent(_this, 'click');
```

Inside your click handler you can check whether the event was fired programmatically:

```
$(document).on('click', '.post a', function(event) {

    // ignore the handler when the click is fired programmatically
    if (event.originalEvent.synthetic) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

This means the `_blank` is still used. It does require the following function to fire an event in most browsers:

```
/**
 * Fire an event handler to the specified node. Event handlers can detect that the event was fired programatically
 * by testing for a 'synthetic=true' property on the event object
 * @param {HTMLNode} node The node to fire the event handler on.
 * @param {String} eventName The name of the event without the "on" (e.g., "focus")
 */
function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
        doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9){
        // the node may be the document itself, nodeType 9 = DOCUMENT_NODE
        doc = node;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

     if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        // Gecko-style approach (now the standard) takes more work
        var eventClass = "";

        // Different events have different event classes.
        // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
        // the event firing is going to fail.
        switch (eventName) {
            case "click": // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
            case "mousedown":
            case "mouseup":
                eventClass = "MouseEvents";
                break;

            case "focus":
            case "change":
            case "blur":
            case "select":
                eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
                break;

            default:
                throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
                break;
        }
        var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);

        var bubbles = eventName == "change" ? false : true;
        event.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        // The second parameter says go ahead with the default action
        node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else  if (node.fireEvent) {
        // IE-old school style
        var event = doc.createEventObject();
        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
};
```

Another problem in your code was that the timeout was not canceled. I changed it to:

```
if (postDoubleClickTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(postDoubleClickTimeout);
}
postDoubleClickTimeout = setTimeout(...);
```

Now

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fsApG

Comment: Chrome is blocking the "click".

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you can prevent the popup-blocker from kicking in when you're trying to open a new window programmatically. I think it's only allowed during the an actual onclick of a link, in your case the `setInterval` means your code will be executed outside of the actual onclick. Remove the `target="_blank"` and the click will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

try ($('.post').get(0)).off('doubletap').on('doubletap', function(event) { use off click.

Comment: also change $(document).off('click').on('click', '.post a', function(event) {